# Changing one NSManaged object changes other objects

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app called Hapistats on the app store. It uses cloudkit. I am in the process of converting all data from cloudkit to Coredata.

I have an entity called **log**, it has a one to many relationship with **activity**.

The problem is when I try and update a log's activities. Lets lay **log1** is a log that has an activity called **activity1**. When I try to add activity1 to the already existing log, **log2**, log1 will no longer have activity1 and log2 will successfully save activity1 to itself.

This happens for every update or new log created. The problem is that apparently there can only be one log with a specific activity.

```
// Edits the log
func editLog(log: Log, rating: Int, activitiesToAddToLog: [Activity]) {
    log.rating = Int16(rating)
    log.removeFromActivities(log.activities) // Empties the activities from the log
    let activitiesOrderedSet = NSOrderedSet(array: activitiesToAddToLog)
    log.addToActivities(activitiesOrderedSet) // Adds all the activites to the log
    saveToPersistentStore()
}
```

Is the only place that calls editLog()

```
@IBAction func saveActivitiesButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    // log is an optional because I use a landing pad for log.
    if let log = log {
        LogController.shared.editLog(log: log, rating: rating, activities: displayActivities[0])true)
    }
}
```

I expect that my code would just add activities to logs when editLog() is called but instead it overrides other logs' activities.

Comment: You need to check your relationships in your core data model - it sounds like it is a "to one" relationship, where you want a "to many"

Comment: In the beginning I said that it was a one to many relationship

Comment: But what about the inverse. It sounds like that is a to-one

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks, but the activity model has a one to0 many relationship as well. But the code above looks good no?

Comment: Why do you call ` log.removeFromActivities`?  All you should do is add the activity to the set. It is a set so if it is already present, it won't have any effect. If it isn't then it will be added. Core data manages the inverse for you

Comment: It was more for testing purposes, I originally had it just make the log.activities = activitiesToAddToLog. I figured it out though by building on generic device and restarting Xcode. 3 Day problem solved thank you good sire

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It was a Xcode issue. It wasn't actually being one to many so I re added it and built on a generic device and it suddenly worked.